# Sony Vegas Pro 12 - 4/3 video wrongly considered as 16/9

Tags: video, video-editor, vegas-pro, aspect

I am digitalizing Super 8 film with a [dedicated Somikon scanner](https://www.somikon.fr/produit/scanner-de-pellicule-pour-films-8-mm-et-super-8-2/).

It outputs H264 - MPEG-4 AVC films in 4/3 (1440x1080).
When I open these films directly with VLC, there are displayed in 4/3, which is fine.

Then I add them in Sony Vegas Pro 12 to edit/modify them, but Vegas Pro believes that they are 16/9 clips: although the `Project [Projet]` and `Visualization [Visualisation]` fields are in 4/3, the `Display [Affichage]` is in 16/9 (600x338) by default:[image: Display in 16/9]

I have to uncheck the `Simulate the peripheral image ratio [Simuler le format d'image du périphérique]` item to get back the original 4/3 aspect ratio:
[image: Display back in 4/3]

When I render the project, Vegas generates a video in 4/3 with the right resolution (1440x1080), but the video player sofwares (VLC for example, see capture below) believe it should be displayed with a 16/9 aspect ratio.

[image: Correct resolution]

[image: But wrong default aspect ratio]

In conclusion, the resolution is good all along, but the default aspect ratio is wrongly set to 16/9 by/in Vegas Pro.

Is there a way to avoid that in the first place?

Or is there a way to correct it afterwards (once the rendered file is created)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not manage to solve the source problem, but I found how to overcome the consequences.

It is indeed possible to edit the aspect ratio of the rendered video using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT_FILE> -aspect 4:3 -c copy <OUTPUT_FILE>
```

Comment: I re-wrap containers all the time so my fussy Vegas install will play nice with them. This command moves really fast, right? So that makes it a good solution.